# Mechanical Turk: Using HTML in the API

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

Question for anyone who's used Mechanical Turk: Is it possible to take an HTML template created on Mechanical Turk's website, and then create more HITs based on that template from the command line tools or API?

---

According to the API docs, it's not possible to create new HTML and add it...from the API. However, what I want to do here is use a HIT template I already created. It would seem like there should be a way to use that template (and load up new data in the API), since Amazon already approved it and I'm using it for HITs already. But I haven't seen a way in the documentation to do so.

---

The main reason I want the HTML is so I can apply styles that I can't apply by using a questions file. If there was some sort of "rich" question file, that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the API has been updated to allow this using `HITLayout`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITLayoutArticle.html.

Answer (score 2):

You could post a job on Mechanical Turk to have a person take your template and insert your data into it for each HIT you want to create.

(yes, this is at least half sarcasm)

Comment: In response to the almost half that isn't sarcasm: This would require giving up my credentials. Technically speaking, I could definitely see myself doing it otherwise. :)

Comment: You would not have to give up your credentials if you have them work remotely through a computer that you control.  Run a web browser on your own computer, restrict it from accessing any account-sensitive pages on mturk, then give them access to it through RDP or VNC or whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I haven't seen a way to use manually created questions from the API.

If you're planning on doing programmatic access, it may be easier to use the API in its entirety (i.e., specify your questions via XML and create HITs from that question):

http://www.codeplex.com/MTurkDotNet (.NET SDK)

The API is pretty easy to use, and there several code samples.

Alternatively, you can use the "External Question" question type which may be better suited -- you can host the entire question form yourself.